# Four players, each received 13 cards, player A saw that their neighbour has ace of spades. What is the probability that player A doesn't have ace.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, conditional-probability, card-games

Four players, each received $13$ cards, player A saw that their neighbour has ace of spades. What is the probability that player A doesn't have ace.

My textbook says it is $$\dfrac{{39 \choose 13}}{{51 \choose 13}},$$ but I have no idea why.

Can someone explain me why this is answer or provide another if this is not correct.

Comment: The textbook is wrong. That is the probability that $A$ did not get any spades.

Comment: Taking  the question to be  correct, the provided answer obviously isn't. Before giving you an answer, what have *you* tried to get a correct answer ?

Comment: "That is the probability that A did not get any spades" hmm shouldn't it be $\frac{{39 \choose 13}}{{52 \choose 13}}$

Comment: No. The ace of spades is known to be on the neighbour's hand. That leaves $51$ cards, of which $39$ are spades.

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  It is **irrelevant** whether the problem is homework.  What counts is whether the protocol is observed.

Answer (score 2):

This is a long-winded comment, that bends if not breaks the rule that an answer should not be provided, for low quality postings.

The reason that I am responding is that the book's answer is wrong.  I question how reasonable it is to ask the OP (i.e. original poster) to show work, when the computation that the OP would be trying to establish is **wrong**.

In a probability problem like this, a Combinatorics answer of $~\dfrac{N}{D}~$ will typically represent (as in this case) that:

- There are $~D~$ equally likely possible ways that event $E_1$ can occur.
- Event $E_2$, which represents a subset of the event $E_1$ can occur in $N$ ways.

---

So, you let $E_1$ represent the event that a player is receiving $13$ cards from a $~51~$ card deck.  That is, since the Ace of Spades has been seen in someone else's hand, the player is (in effect) being dealt $~13~$ cards from a deck with only $~51~$ cards remaining.

This explains the computation of $\displaystyle ~D~ = \binom{51}{13}.$

I agree with the OP that the computation $\displaystyle ~N~ = \binom{39}{13}~$ is wrong.  Instead, the correct computation is $~\displaystyle N = \binom{48}{13}.$

This is because when you remove the three other Aces from the $51$ cards remaining in the deck, you are left with $48$ cards, none of which are an Ace.

So, the probability of not receiving an Ace, from a 51 card deck that contains $3$ Aces is

$$\frac{\binom{48}{13}}{\binom{51}{13}}.$$

---

Most likely explanation is that either the OP mis-stated the problem or that the problem composer made a mistake.  Consider the alternative problem of :

The probability that the player did not receive **any spades**, given that the Ace of spades is known to be in someone else's hand.

This probability would in fact be

$$\frac{\binom{39}{13}}{\binom{51}{13}},$$

and is explained by reasoning that when you remove the $12$ remaining spades from the $51$ card deck, you have $39$ non-spades.  $~\binom{39}{13}~$ represents the number of ways of receiving $~13~$ cards, none of which are spades.